# Error writing countdown timer script

Tags: bash

```
hour_init=$((1)); 
min_init=$((30)); 
sec_init=$((00)); 
hour=$hour_init; 
min=$min_init; 
sec=$sec_init; 
while [ $hour -gt 0]; 
while [ $min -gt 0 ]; 
while [$sec -gt 0]; 
do clear; 
echo $sec | figlet; 
sleep 1; 
sec=$(($sec- 1)); 
done; 
sec=$sec_init; 
min=$(($min- 1)); 
done; 
hour=$($hour- 1); 
min=$min_init; 
sec=$sec_init; 
done;
```

I wrote this piece to get a hour:min:sec based timer. I couldn't however! I am very new to bash scripting. Can someone tell me what I have done wrong here ?

Comment: It looks like you tried to fit it all on one line, but in reality there's practically no upper bound on the number of lines you can use.

Comment: yeah i just wrote this in terminal to get it working

Comment: Embrace the return key.

Comment: even with that the error is still the same :
bash:syntax error near unexpected token 'done'

Comment: Could you kindly write your code in multiple lines? It's painful for others (who'd like to help) to view code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the spaces after `[`s and before `]`s, and this won't loop if you set `sec` to 0 initially (because your loop exits when `sec` is non positive. Also note the `hour=$(($hour- 1))` bit:

```
hour_init=1
min_init=60
sec_init=60
hour=$hour_init
min=30
sec=0
while [ $hour -gt 0 ] 
do
  while [ $min -gt 0 ]; do
    while [ $sec -gt 0 ] 
    do clear
      echo "$hour:$min:$sec"
      sleep 1
      sec=$(($sec- 1))
    done
    sec=$sec_init
    min=$(($min- 1))
  done
  hour=$(($hour- 1))
  min=$min_init
  sec=$sec_init
done
```